# Do Holomorphic functions from the disk to itself have bounded derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $D$ be the unit disk and $f: D \to D$ be a holomorphic function.  Is it true that the derivative of $f$ is bounded?  What about if $f$ is an automorphism of $D$ that fixes $0$?

Comment: See [Blaschke_product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) for some conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the derivative of such an $f$ need not be bounded. Example: For $|z|\le 1,$ define

$$f(z) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}.$$

Then $f(\mathbb D) \subset \mathbb D.$ For $|z|<1$ we have

$$f'(z) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{n}.$$

As $r\to 1^-,$ $f'(r) \to \infty.$ (In fact $f(r)$ is on the order of $\ln(1/(1-r)).$

Your second question is easy: An automorphism of $\mathbb D$ that fixes $0$ is a rotation, so $|f'(z)| \equiv 1.$

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be describing what's commonly known as the Schwarz Lemma, which states that if $f:D \to D$ with $f(0) = 0 $ is a holomorphic function, then $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ for all $z \in D$, and if there is some $z_0$ such that $|f(z_0)| = |z_0|$, then there is a $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z) = e^{i\theta}z$.